# best way to handle bookmarking in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to get an idea of how to do this properly.

Say I have a **photos model** and I want users to be able to bookmark them ... so I have a **bookmarks model** that belongs to both users and photos. What is the best way to implement the creation of the bookmark?

Should I have a **bookmarks controller** with a **create** method and just use that ... or should I add a **bookmark** method to the **photos controller** and just do the bookmark creation there?

I've done it both ways before, but I wanted to get a feel for what other folks think. I like the bookmark create method idea, but I don't like that I have to construct a POST with variables just to do bookmark something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either - this is a personal preference thing. I would decide based on this criteria: Do you want to show the object by itself on a page, are there views just for bookmarks? For example, do you plan to have a URL like http://...../users/12/bookmarks to display all bookmarks of a user? If on the other hand you only use the bookmarks on other pages I'd add the methods to add/delete bookmarks to that controller. If you want to add it to more than one you may use a module to avoid duplicating the code. Myself, I recently went THAT route, I only had a create- and a destroy-function for bookmarks and don't display them by themselves, but only in bigger context. As is usual for create/destroy functions, neither has a view, they both redirect back to the item#show page where they were called from (in my app).